# Why can't I connect to my MongoDB in DataGrip?

Tags: mongodb, datagrip

I tried to create MongoDB database in DataGrip, but I can't do anything in this database

I did test connection and here is what I got:

```
DBMS: Mongo DB
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=mixed
Driver: MongoDB JDBC Driver (ver. 1.13, JDBC4.2)
Effective version: UNKNOWN (ver. 0.0)
Ping: 10 sec, 417 ms (keep-alive query results in error)

Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. 
Client view of cluster state is {
    type=UNKNOWN, 
    servers=[{
        address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, 
        exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, 
        caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}
    }].
```

[properties screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCac1.png)

Unlike MongoDB my PostgreSQL database works fine.

I tried to change drivers, recreate database.

**Solution**: install MongoDB

Comment: Port 5432 is generally PostgreSQL, not MongoDB, so it looks like you configured the wrong port, and you attempt to connect to your PostgreSQL server, which then terminates the connection as it doesn't receive the PostgreSQL connection handshake. The default port for MongoDB is 27017. Check your MongoDB configuration for its actual port and specify the right port.

Comment: I changed port to 27017, but there is another error "Exception opening socket", i'll edit post

Comment: Do you have MongoDB server up and running in this port?  Can you connect using any other tool?

Comment: @YuriWin i created local database in DataGrip. Tried to connect by MongoDB Compass but error "connect ECONNREFUSED"

Comment: @Morye In DataGrip you create a data source which connects to database server. Only after successful connection you can create a database. So do you have Mongodb server running on localhost?

Comment: @YuriWin thank you for explanation. Actually I didn't have installed MongoDB, lol. I've already edited post, where wrote solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create MongoDB in DataGrip, you can just connect to existent server (local or remote).

Comment: Did they prevent create database on purpose? I can not create new database with DataGrip version 2023.2.1

Comment: Have you tried to invoke `use DATABASE_NAME` in console?